# what does "cd //" do in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and in bash, when I type `cd //` I get to what looks like root. However, the `pwd` command yields `//`. I can create files, and everything seems to behave like normal bash, just with the `//`  replacing the familiar `/` as root. It only seems to work with two slashes. any other number just gives the single slash version.

Is this an Ubuntu or bash quirk? What does it do?

Comment: While the question was about Bash on OS X, the answer there applies to Ubuntu as well. `//` has a special meaning although it usually defaults to `/`, and multiple subsequent slashes are collapsed into one.

Comment: I googled around for a while, and didn't find the above question. thanks for pointing it out. I'll close this one out.